# How To Convert CSV File to OpenTSDB Format

Tags: java, file, csv, converters, opentsdb

Is there currently a way out there to convert CSV files to the OpenTSDB format? It was suggested to me to write a custom Java program to do this conversion, but I'm not really sure where to start there. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you please extend your question with example `CSV` content and what you expects for each line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would create a class that can read from that CSV, you can use OpenCSV library, you can find information all around the internet regarding that library. 
And after that extract what you need (if you have to - I am not sure if you only want simply just convert or to parse the file and get info from inside the file.)
And then you have to know your OpenTSDB format and do the magic you have to do. Your question is a bit too general, can you be more specific?
You have the link with the OpenTSDB documentation [here](http://opentsdb.net/docs/build/html/index.html).

Hopefully I have helped you a bit.

Comment: I was looking into OpenCSV, and I think it could be a viable solution. However, I don't see any examples online of how doing asynchronous conversions. Do you know of any good tutorials on how to do this with OpenCSV?

Comment: I have found some example on how to read / write csv files. https://www.callicoder.com/java-read-write-csv-file-opencsv/ I think this a pretty good tutorial and it is based on java. Can you be more specific on what do you mean by asynchronous conversions ? I mean the use case behind your needs. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks, that looks helpful. I guess I was thinking if we want to process multiple CSV files, for performance reasons we would probably want to do it asynchronously?

Comment: Take it step by step, do the conversion, make it work in a simple and useful way, then think about how to do it async. If the simple method is fast enough for your needs you might not need async conversions. If you need, then I am sure there is a way.

Comment: Good advice. I'll go with that approach. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to help, if this answer solved your problem please mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark next to the answer. If you have more questions then please ask! :)